# Transistor replacement for Novak Electronics

Tags: transistors, pcb, identification

I am looking for a replacement transistor for a discontinued electronic speed controller by Novak Electronics - Ceased operation in 2016.

The following is the information written on the transistor

1. 6726 S211 1435 -
2. Transistor is surface mount.  Has 3 points that mount to PCB on centre and out casing also solders to contacts on PCB

[image: Top]

[image: bottom]

Comment: The key bit not mentioned in the question is the I-diode-R logo of International Rectifier (top right).

Comment: @TooTea If you've seen one before, the package style alone is enough to know it's IR/Infineon. No one else makes parts in DirectFET packages.

Answer (score 10):

This is an Infineon (formerly International Rectifier) [IRF6726M](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf6726mpbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355ed61db1a98), in IR's proprietary DirectFET MT package.

The part is obsolete, but it may be possible to replace it with an [IRF6613](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf6613pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e82b9b1a0d), which has a slightly higher voltage rating of 40 V (vs. 30 V), a slightly lower gate charge of 42 nC (vs 51 nC), but a higher on-resistance of 3.4 mΩ (vs 1.3 mΩ). However, the IRF6613 is the only part in DirectFET MT that's not obsolete, so your only other option is getting IRF6726Ms at inflated prices from non-authorized resellers.

It is also *possible*, though I have not tried this, that a DirectFET MX part might fit on a DirectFET MT footprint. If that's the case, the [IRF6727M](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRF6727MTRPBF/4695497), which seems to be a nearly identical part to the IRF6726M just with a smaller die size, could be used instead. The outer drain pads will definitely line up (they both use the M can size), but I can't be entirely certain about the inner pads. Given the low price to buy just one (only US$2.50 as of this writing), it might be worth buying one and seeing if it works, and going to the IRF6613 if not.

Comment: Hearth, Thank you very much for your assistance